# Is there any model to get context of each customer's review in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification

I have data with 20k comments written by customers. I want to retrieve or pull context of each customer's review using Python.

Example:

1. " This shirt size is too small for me". Here in this sentence he is talking about product size so context should be like "Product size".
2. "The price is too high i can get this product for less cost in amazon.". Here in this sentence he is talking about product price so context should be like "Product price".
3. "I was waiting for my shoes and i got it very late". Context should be "Shipment".

Which model should I apply to get this in Python and what are all the preprocessing steps I have to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you're asking is quite open ended and would require a substantial answer. It would be helpful if you can show specifically where you are at in your work, and what exactly you need help with. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not sentiment analysis but rather text classification. Please update your tags accordingly

Comment: SO is for programming questions, this question would fit better on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question about which much has been written elsewhere, so I'm not going to go into great detail here, but rather provide some helpful links that should get you going in the right direction.

First of all, it will help you to have a broad overview of the problem space. You are attempting to tackle the problem of [text (or document) classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification). Specifically, your problem is, "Given some (arbitrary length?) text, produce one (or more?) (manually curated or automatically learned?) topic(s) associated with that text." As you haven't been specific in your question, you'll need to fill in the questions embedded in that statement yourself. [This article](https://monkeylearn.com/text-classification/) seems like a decent and only moderately technical overview. As it mentions, there are both manually specified rule-based and machine learning-based approaches to the problem.

As for doing this in python specifically, again, much has been written that you can easily search for, though I imagine you might be struggling somewhat for the correct vocabulary to search with, so I'll help you out. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-in-python-dd95d264c802) looks like an excellent article with example scripts that will walk you through the problems of preprocessing, model building, and analysis. It was the first google hit for "python text classification."

Finally, I'll say that this is a complex area for which there will not be any valuable quick and dirty solutions for a beginner. You're going to need to invest the time to understand the field in order to learn how to build an accurate and meaningful model. There are of course a great many business-oriented services that will do this in more of a black box fashion for you, and there are also cloud services like [SageMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-text-classification.html) and a host of others, but as it seems like you're interested in rolling your own model, there's no substitute for spending the time to learn.